# How to encrypt password before post from login form?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, yii

I have a `Login` form in `yii` which required `username` and `password`. My problem is that password is plain text so it may cause security issue. For this i have `md5` password before submitting form via ajax

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
        <p class="hint">
            Hint: You may login with <tt>demo/demo</tt>.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="row rememberMe">
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row submit">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login',array('id'=>'submit')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
<script>
$("#submit").click(function(){    

var password = $("#LoginForm_password").val();

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: '<?php echo Yii;;app()->createUrl("user/encrptpassword")?>',      
        data: {'password': password},         
        success:function(data){
         $("#LoginForm_password").val(data);
       }
    }); 

</script>



public function actionEncrptpassword(){

echo md5($_POST['password']);

}
```

But this is also not safe as ajax post data is also visible on inspecting.

Please let me know how can i `encrpt` my password before submit form

Comment: Implementing SSL solves this problem .Your aproach is a workaround. But you can consider implementing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography There some libs for GPG for javascript and php.

Comment: @rNix i can't implement SSL now because of some issue. Please let me know if i can do it without this

Comment: @user1234 then maybe you should work on resolving that issue, instead - most web-server-tutorials include an SSL section, certificates are free now, it's best practice to secure your communication, anyway - what' stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

Use SSL, that's the whole point of it. http://clouldflare.com gives free SSL for any domain.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GPG. You generate a pair of keys: public and private.

1. You use public key to encrypt user's password with javascript on client-side: https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs
2. Then you should use your private key to decrypt message on server-side: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.gnupg.php

Notice: client-side library depends on a user's browser and can be buggy. Use it if you can control this.

To avoid [Replay attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) you can use a random token and store it in user's session. You display it on login form, grab it for hashing on client-side and use it for validation on server-side from user's session. This and other options are described on wiki page.