# How to md5 jQuery variable?

Tags: php, jquery

I need to `md5` a password before sending it via post

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="password" id="password"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="encrpt()">

<script>
function encrpt(){
    var password = $("#password").val();
$("#password").val("<?php echo md5(1234); ?>");
    }
</script>
```

This code works fine and `md5` value of 12345 set into password field but whenever I use jQuery password value it gives wrong value like

```
$("#password").val("<?php echo md5('<script>password</script>'); ?>");
```

I need to `md5` value of the password which I entered into field.

Comment: Why do you need the md5 value before posting it? You can md5 it after post in PHP. Why use MD5 when there's a lot better function called password_hash? http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798145/how-to-encrypt-password-before-post-from-login-form

Comment: why are u using here? u can use in php file

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585159/how-to-convert-password-into-md5-in-jquery

Comment: md5? but why man?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use PHP md5 in javascript function. You have to use external JS library for that. For example : https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5

so your code should be like this :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-md5/2.5.0/js/md5.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="password" id="password"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="encrpt()">

<script>
    function encrpt() {
        var password = $("#password").val();
        $("#password").val(md5(password));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery md5 library, since there's no way to do it using pure jQuery: https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CrypotJs](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) for the purpose

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">      </script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="password" id="password"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="encrpt()">

  <script>
   function encrpt(){
   var password = $("#password").val();
   $("#password").val(CryptoJS.MD5(password).toString());
   }
</script>
```